# Django's FileField open(mode='r') opening as bytestring instead of string

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model with a FileField that saves a text file, here's how I'm accessing it:

```
    report = MyMoodel.objects.get()
    document_report = report.document
    document_report.open(mode='r')
    print(type(document_report.read()))
```

The resulting "type" is

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

Shouldn't I be receiving a string instead of bytestrings? Am I using open incorrectly?

EDIT:

Here's before opening and after:

```
    print('Before Open', document_report._file)
    document_report.open(mode='r')
    print('After Open', document_report._file)

Before Open None
After Open /Users/stupidfatcat/Development/myapp/reports/2017/04/18/test_file_2eGEcd3
```

Comment: What are the contents of `document_report._file`? `open()` does not re-open the file when it is already open and the default mode is binary.

Comment: @dhke before open it's None, after open it's the actual file

Comment: @dhke added the output to the question

Comment: `._file` is the cached file object. `FileField` obtains it by forwarding to [`storage.open()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.open). Does the storage object also give you a binary file? i.e. what does [`document_report.storage.open(document_report.name, mode='r')`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L77) return?

Comment: It's returning me /Users/stupidfatcat/Development/myapp/reports/2017/04/18/test_file_z7OT6DD and after .read() it actually returns a string. Not entirely sure what's going on.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat I've the same issue. There have been opened some Django tickets w.r.t. this. Probably this issue is not fixed in Django yet.